# Are $L^1$-compactly-supported functions in $L^{\infty}$?

Tags: real-analysis, integration, measure-theory

Let $\lambda$ be a $\sigma$-finite Borel measure on $\mathbb{R}^m$ and suppose that $f$ is an integrable function, the essential supported on some compact $K\subseteq \mathbb{R}^m$.  Then is the essential supremum of $f$ finite? I.e.: $f \in L^{\infty}_{\lambda}(\Sigma)$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't believe so. Take the function 
$$
f(x) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{x}}, \quad x \in (0, 1] , 
$$
$f(x) = 0$ elsewhere. Then the support of $f$ is $[0,1]$, $f$ is integrable according to WolframAlpha, but $f$ is unbounded.

Comment: One can also see $f$ is integrable explicitly: $\int_0^1 \frac{1}{\sqrt{x}} dx = 2\sqrt{x}|_{0}^1 = 2$.